# how would jquery deferred work in this situation?

Tags: jquery

Using callbacks, I have the following code

```
var TK = {
    List: [],
    getSectionA: function(listName, callback)
    {
        var arrayList = [];
        $.get('ajax/test.html', {sendName: listName}, function(data) {

              $.each(data, function()
              {
                     arrayList = data;
              });
         callback(arrayList);
        });       

    }

};
```

calling the function

```
   $("#dropDownList").change(function()
   {
       TK.getSectionA(fileName, function(data)
       {
             TK.List = data;
             alert(TK.List); // This works ok...
       });

             alert(TK.List); // This does not work when calling using this property outside the callback..
   });
```

How can I get this to work outside the callback function which is in another function

Comment: The second alert _cannot_ work. You _have_ to wait somehow

Comment: @JanDvorak that's the whole point of the question

Comment: @popnoodles Are you suggesting I post this as  an answer?

Comment: "how would jquery deferred work in this situation" = "I know it needs to wait. How do I do that?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the jQuery get() function returns the promise interface that allows you to add as many functions as you want to handle the get() completing either successfully (done()) or failing (fail) or just completing either way (always()).

The promise interface is the same as the deferred but only has the "read only" methods so you can't interfere with the process but you can see what happens.

If you return the promise, it can be used to do whatever you want:

```
    var TK = {
        List: [],
        getSectionA: function(listName, callback)
        {
            var arrayList = [];
            return $.get('ajax/test.html', {sendName: listName}, function(data) {

                  $.each(data, function()
                  {
                         arrayList = data;
                  });
             callback(arrayList);
            });       

        }

};
```

Call it something like this:

```
 TK.getSectionA(fileName, function(data)
       {
             TK.List = data;
             alert(TK.List); // This works ok...
       }).always(function() {
             alert("Get ended: " + TK.List);
       });
```

You can read it on this page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ but have to skip down to a paragraph that has "promise" in it.

Comment: Does this means I can now use TK.List anywhere in the code with the updated array information? For example, I need to use TK.List somewhere else in the code...

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene only in a callback to `always` or `done`; otherwise you could be trying to access `TK` too soon

Comment: I think the jQuery.ajax() to which I linked explains it better for this context. Also, that paragraph has a link on it to the actual 'deferred' page within jQuery. Thanks for adding the direct link.